# How to know what part of speech is "there" in some cases?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

I've been doing some ELA homework and I noticed that '*there*' is not always the same POS.

It seems to be an adverb, a noun, a pronoun, and several other POS in various contexts.

How would one know what part of speech the word '*there*' is in a given case?

Comment: [***There** is a glass **there***, where the first *there* is a pronoun (the so-called 'existential *there*') and the other *there* is an adverb.](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/ask-teacher/90063-there-pronoun-adverb.html)

Comment: It's a very strange pronoun; it's a non-referential dummy created by _There_-insertion. But it can Raise like a real NP, just like the dummy _it_'s in _It's raining, It's a long way to Tipperary,_  and _It's unfortunate for you that you witnessed that_. So I guess, if you're not playing with a full set of POS, "Pronoun" is probly the safest bet.

Answer (score 2):

If you would just look in the dictionary........ [[link](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/there?s=t)]

> adverb
>
> 1. in or at that place (opposed to here ): She is there now.
> 2. at that point in an action, speech, etc.: He stopped there for applause.
> 3. in that matter, particular, or respect: His anger was justified there.
> 4. into or to that place; thither: We went there last year.
> 5. (used by way of calling attention to something or someone): There they go.
> 6. in or at that place where you are: Well, hi there.

Comment: It's easier to just remember if *there* is modifying a verb, it's an adverb. "She **is there** now", "He **stopped there** for applause", "His anger was **justified there**", "We **went there** last year", "**There** they **go**". Number 6 ("Well, hi there") is the exception, and it seems arguable because it's a colloquial fixed phrase.