# What's the subject of "There is my biscuit!" ? And how about "There is one biscuit left"?

Tags: grammar, subjects, there-is, syntactic-analysis, be

What's the subject, grammatically speaking, of these sentences?

1. *There is my biscuit!*
2. *My biscuit is there!*
3. *There is one biscuit left.*

I don't really know how to analyze these. The following observations seem to be relevant, though:

- The verb *to be* doesn't take an object.
- In the first two sentences, *there* is a demonstrative pronoun. It is therefore *potentially* a subject, I think. I don't know what part of speech is taken by *there* in the third sentence.
- In favour of reading *my biscuit* and *one biscuit* as the subjects is that if there were more than one biscuit then, in each case, the verb would become plural (*There are my biscuits!* etc.)
- In favour of reading *one biscuit* as the subject of the third sentence is that if we recast it as (the slightly unidiomatic) *There remains one biscuit*, it seems that *one biscuit* would have to be the subject.

All of this leads me tentatively towards thinking that *my biscuit* and *one biscuit* are the subjects here, but I'm not totally confident about this.

One other possibility: since *to be* doesn't take an object, does that mean it can have two subjects? In *I am he*, presumably both *I* and *he* are subjects, if neither is an object?

Comment: in *I am he*, "I" is the subject, *he* is part of the predicate: "*is he*"

Comment: Boy I wish you hadn't asked this question. It's corker. As it goes I'm half way through writing an answer for it kind of by accident. Hmm, uni work or interesting question? OK, here goes then...

Comment: @Araucaria I'm a computer programmer and mathematician! This isn't uni work at all, just an interesting question.

Comment: @chiastic-security Do you mind if I do an answer for sentence 3 and then go back and edit in sentences 1 and 2, just in case this gets closed?

Comment: @Araucaria Go for it. (But hopefully it won't get closed--it really doesn't seem like a dupe to me. And there's only 1 close vote on it at the moment, and it takes 5 to close it.)

Comment: Or only one. I would strongly advise against answering in comments, and advise actually writing an answer. I'll hold off closing for now; can't speak for anyone else.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the duplicate question is visible only if you are the poster/questioner. Otherwise it appears only as a comment, and in your case it's well hidden! (No chance of anyone being unduly influenced). In other words, I don't see any any "banner" hovering above your post. You might want to double check this with someone else though. By the way did you read [@Daniel's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/36949/44619) in the dupe? Why doesn't it answer your question?

Comment: Although I admit, after reading the dupe more carefully perhaps I was too rash in my decision. It is asking a different question. I will retract my close vote.

Comment: Regarding your "Please note" notice - your question's also about the *function* not the part of speech! :)

Comment: "To be" takes a "complement", not an object, "I am she" means I = she.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Sentence 3:*** ***Existential Subjects***: ***Words, Phrases and Functions***

[A Comparison of Sentences and analysis of Sentences 1 & 2 forthcoming]

> There's one biscuit left.

So now the burning question is: What is the subject of this existential sentence? This isn't as easy as it looks. If we want to answer this question we need to really understand what a subject is. And if we want to understand what a subject is, we need to understand the difference between a *function* in a sentence, and a part of speech, for example a *Noun*, or  type of phrase, for example a *Noun Phrase*. Being a Noun or Noun Phrase and being a Subject are completely different. A Noun  *can* be a Subject but it can do many other jobs as well. For example, a Noun  can also be an Object, a Modifier in another Noun Phrase, or the Complement of a Preposition:

- I like monkeys.   (Direct Object)
- I'm a monkey fanatic. (Modifier in Noun Phrase)
- I am scared of monkeys. (Complement of Preposition)

So Nouns seem to be a type of word. The different jobs that a word can do are called *functions*. The words *Subject*, *Object*, *Modifier*, *Complement* are all different jobs or *functions*.  There are many other types of function.

Very often we see a group of words, not just one word, doing some particular function in a sentence:

> The mice like cheese

Here, the Subject is two words: *The mice*. The most important word in that group is the Noun *mice*. We call the chunk of words *the mice* a Noun Phrase. We can have very long Noun Phrases:

> I am *a very keen monkey fanatic*.

Here *a very keen monkey fanatic* has the job of Complement of the Verb *BE*.

This big Noun Phrase has some words in it that seem to work together. For example the word *very* seems to go together with the word *keen*. The answer to *How keen is he?* is *Very keen!*. In the chunk *very keen*, the Adjective *keen* seems to be the main word. This chunk is an Adjective Phrase. So, we have a big Noun Phrase functioning as Complement of *BE*, and inside the Complement we have an Adjective Phrase functioning as *Modifier*. So large phrases have smaller phrases inside them. Every phrase always has its own function.

Sometimes we might want to do a test, to see which chunks of words go together in one phrase. One well-known test is to use a substitute word to replace part of a sentence. Usually, if the substitute word replaces a group of words, then that whole group is one phrase and will have its own function. We can do this test with *The mice like cheese*. Let's use the word *They*:

> They like cheese.

So the word *they* replaced the words *The mice*. This shows that *the mice* is one phrase - a Noun Phrase. It also indicates that *The mice* has one function - it's the Subject.

There is one very special function we haven't talked about. Us teachers and linguists are a bit naughty; we say things like *Subject Verb Object*, things like that. Of course *Verb* is a type of word, not a function! Verbs can have many functions, they can be Subjects, for instance:

> To love is the most important thing.

But there is one function that can only be carried out by Verb Phrases (in English). No other words or types of phrase can do this job:

> I smoke.

Here the job being done by the Verb (Phrase) *smoke* is the job of *Predicate*. In the same way that every sentence in English has a Verb, every English sentence has a Predicate. This is the job that the Verb Phrase does. What I want to show you now, is that the functions of *Subject* and *Object* are not equal. The *Subject* is a far more important and fundamental part of any sentence than the *Object*. Let's do a substitution test with the sentence:

> The mice like cheese.

We know that we can substitute *they* for *The mice*. Let's use an auxiliary verb as another substitute word. We know that auxiliaries can 'stand in' for other words in sentences. The sentence is present simple so we need the auxiliary *DO*. Look what happens to the sentence:

> They do.

We can see that both of the words *like* and *cheese* have been replaced. This shows that *like cheese* is one phrase. The head word is the Verb *like*, so *like cheese* is a Verb Phrase. The function or job of the Verb Phrase in the sentence is *Predicate*.

Inside the Verb Phrase (the Predicate) , there is a small Noun Phrase, *cheese*. The function of *cheese* inside this Verb Phrase is *Complement* of the verb. It is a special kind of complement: an *Object*. This test shows something very important about Subjects that makes them completely different from Objects and other complements. Subjects are *outside* the Predicate. We can say that they are *external* to the Verb Phrase. Other complements of the verb are *internal* complements. They live inside the Verb Phrase and *inside* the Predicate. If we replace the Verb Phrase, all the Complements of the verb are replaced too. In fact, everything outside of the Subject is part of the Predicate and will be replaced in a substitution test like this.

Hold on a minute! This sounds like the job of *Subject* is about how sentences are made, how we build them. What about *meaning*? *Subjects* must have a special meaning, mustn't they? Some people say that verbs tell us about *actions*. It is said that the person or people that *do* the actions are the Subjects. So in *Bob punched Nelson*, the Subject is *Bob*.  In this sentence this is true, but in many sentences it isn't. In the sentence *Bob is a monkey fanatic*, Bob isn't doing anything. The sentence is just telling us about a quality or chracteristic of Bob. There's no action here. Let's do a substitution test for this sentence with the pronoun *he* and the auxiliary verb *BE*:

> He is.

Here we can see that we have a subject and a predicate, even though there's no action and no person doing the action. Ok, so maybe that's not a good test because *BE* here is used with a stative meaning. How about a sentence like *Bob was punched by Nelson*. We can ask the question *Who was punched by Nelson?* The answer will be:

> Bob was.

Here we see *was* being used for *was punched by Nelson*. Again the sentence has two parts, a Subject *Bob* and the Predicate *was punched by Nelson*. Now here *Bob* wasn't doing the punching, he received the punches. In a passive sentence like this the person doing the action appears in the Verb Phrase. So the semantic role of the Subject in the sentence, what that person does or doesn't do, is not significant in terms of it being the Subject. Notice again that the Subject is *external* - it's outside the Predicate. We do have names for the person who does something and the person it is done to and so forth. They are called *thematic roles*. In both sentences *Bob was punched by Nelson* and *Nelson punched Bob*, Nelson has the thematic role of *agent*. Bob has the thematic role of *patient*.

Subjects, it seems, are indeed about the *structure* of the sentence. They *are* about how we build sentences. They are not about meaning, in the sense that they are not about what the Subject is or isn't doing. We have other words to talk about such meaning. Subjects are about grammar, syntax, not meaning.

Let's review what we've looked at. We have talked about how parts of speech and functions are different. We showed that the basic parts of any English sentence are the Subject and the Predicate. Objects and any other complements of the verb are found inside the Predicate. Because the Predicate always has a Verb as it Head, we say that Subjects are *external* to the Verb Phrase. Objects and any other parts are *internal*.

Now let's look again at the first example sentence in this post:

> There is one biscuit left.

We could ask the question *Is there one biscuit left?* The answer would be:

> There is.

Here the auxiliary verb *is* is standing in for the whole Verb Phrase. The Predicate therefore is *is one biscuit left*. These are the words that have been 'replaced' by *is*. This shows that *one biscuit left* is internal to the Verb Phrase. It cannot be the Subject here. It must be a Complement of the verb *BE*. However, we do still see the word *There*. This shows that *There* is not part of the Predicate. It must, therefore, be the Subject! In fact in all sentences like this with expletive *there* as the first word, *there* is the subject.

For an introduction to constituency tests and all that jazz, I recommend *English Syntax and Argumentation* Bas Aarts 2008 3rd Edition.

Comment: Phew! Thanks! I can see why you needed to write it in stages!

Comment: It's not plagiarism if you wrote it.

Comment: @KitFox I suppose it's not really, no! Just didn't want to hide the fact that I didn't write it for this post originally :)

Comment: (+1) - Both exhaustive & exhausting!

Answer (score 10):

> 1. *There is my biscuit.*
> 2. *My biscuit is there.*
> 3. *There is one biscuit left.*

(1) and (2) are locatives, and *there* is a locative adverb indicating the location of the biscuit.
The structure is identical, but (1) is transformed from (2). Locative sentences can do that:

- *My sister is over there, by the weeping willow.*
- *Over there, by the weeping willow, is my sister.*

*My sister* is the subject in both cases (it's *my biscuit* in the OQ), and of course there is no object.
Locative sentences are intransitive. The locative phrase (*there* in the OQ) is the predicate.

(3), however, is a different kettle of fish. The *there* occurring in (3) is not a locative, but a dummy.
The dummy *there* is inserted by [*There*-Insertion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/149513/15299), a syntactic rule that transforms sentences like

- *One biscuit is left ~ A unicorn is in the garden ~ Someone is here to see you.*

to synonymous sentences with dummy *there*

- *There's one biscuit left ~ There's a unicorn in the garden ~ There's someone here to see you.*
  (One **can** say *There is*, but it's far commoner to start a *There*-Insertion sentence with *There's*
  -- even when the postposed subject is plural -- *There's some people here to see you*).

The question of what the subject is in a *There*-Insertion sentence is a vexing one.
If the sentences are synonymous they should have the same subject, and traditionally it's not *there*.
One can agree the verb with the postposed subject NP, producing plurals

- *There are nine and sixty ways of constructing tribal lays

  -- and **every single one of them is right**.* (Kipling, ["In the Neolithic Age"](http://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/poems_neolithic.htm))

However, there is considerable evidence that the *there* is considered to be the subject in some cases.
For instance, dummy *there* behaves as the subject with [Subject-Raising](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf), and can even be passivized:

- *They believe **Mark** to be the winner. ==> **Mark** is believed to be the winner.*
- *They believe **there** to be no winner yet. ==> **There** is believed to be no winner yet.*
- *For **Mark** to have won seems likely. ==> **Mark** seems likely to have won.*
- *For **there** to be no winner yet seems likely. ==> **There** seems likely to be no winner yet.*

The problem seems to be that the English concept `Subject` has a number of definitions and tests,
and they don't always give the same result, since the Subject-Raising and Subject-Verb Agreement
rules don't use the same definitions.

That means you can say that the Subject is *my biscuit* in one sense, and *there* in another sense.
This may not be what your teacher is looking for; but it's English.

Comment: Thank you! (But I can't comment on what my English teacher is looking for, since I haven't seen her for over 20 years. If I bump into her, I'll be sure to ask.)

Answer (score 4):

***Part 1***: ***subject tests***

> What's the subject, grammatically speaking, of these sentences?
>
> 1. There is my biscuit!
> 2. My biscuit is there!
> 3. There is one biscuit left.

At first glance, sentences 1 and 2, seem to be about the *LOCATION* of the biscuit. Both sentences could be replies for example to the question: Where's my biscuit?

- Where's my biscuit?
- There's my biscuit! / My biscuit's there!

Let's call sentences 1 & 2 ‘locative’ sentences. Notice, though, that sentence 1 is ambiguous. There's another much less likely reading. Consider:

- What can I give her to eat? I've got no cake, no sandwiches. There's my biscuit, I suppose. I could give her that.

Here *There's my biscuit* doesn't seem to include a 'pointy' kind of *there*. It seems more like sentence 3. It's saying something like *A biscuit exists which I could give her*. We'll assume, though, that sentence 1, like sentence 2 *is* meant to be a locative sentence. This is the natural reading, given the exclamation mark and some of the Original Poster's comments.

Sentence 3 doesn't seem to be about the location of a biscuit. It seem to be about the existence of a biscuit. We could give sentence 3 as a reply to in the following:

- Have we eaten all the biscuits?
- There's one biscuit left.

We'll call sentence 3 an ‘existential’ sentence. Now, that sentence 3 has a very different meaning to sentence 1 is highly intriguing, because they look as if they're put together in exactly the same way. Both sentences have the form: *There* + *BE* + Noun Phrase. Weird.

There could be two reasons for this. Firstly, it's possible that one of the items that occurs in both sentences is actually not really one item. It could for example be a homonym, in other words a completely different word with the same spelling and, potentially, the same sound. A second reason, could be that the real structure of the sentences is actually very different. In other words *X* might be a Subject in one sentence and an Object in the other. This is of course the issue at the heart of this investigation.

***Locative sentences 1 & 2***

We'll take sentence 2 first. It seems the most straightforward. We've said that perhaps there are homonyms hiding in these sentences. If there are, that's going to affect our understanding of what the Subject is. Typically, but not always, Subjects are nouns or Noun Phrases. Complements of the verb *BE* are usually either Noun Phrases, Adjective Phrases or Preposition Phrases. Adjuncts (sections of the sentence that aren't grammatically necessary that we tag on to give extra information) are usually Preposition Phrases or Adverb Phrases. So if one of the words is a noun in one sentence and an adverb in another, this will bear upon our investigation. We need to know what the parts of speech are in each sentence.

- My biscuit is there!

Well, *my biscuit* seems to be a straightforward Noun Phrase consisting of a determiner, *my*, and a noun, *biscuit*. There must be a verb in the sentence and it looks like the only candidate is *is*. So far, so good. How about *there*? This is an important question. John Lawler in his post here has said it's an adverb. The Original Poster thinks it's a noun, in fact, a pronoun. Various dictionaries will give different answers - both noun and adverb. The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language says *there*'s a preposition and so does the Oxford Modern English Grammar. And, indeed, *there* is actually a preposition.

Hold on! You can't take my word over a dictionary's, over John Lawler's or over the Original Poster's! This is a very important question for our investigation! It's also highly contentious. Let's look at some evidence.

Superficially, *there* doesn't look like a typical adverb. It has no *-ly* on the end of it. On the other hand, it does look quite like a pronoun. It has one syllable. It only has one part ( - *looked* in contrast is one syllable but has two parts *look* and *ed*). It cannot take 's' as a plural marker - there is no word *theres* in English. At the same time, prepositions share many of these characteristics too. They are typically monosyllabic and so forth too. So far, *there* looks more like a pronoun or preposition. How about the syntax?:

Typical adverbs can freely modify adjectives. Pronouns and prepositions usually can't:

- beautifully melodious / extremely happy /very interesting
- there melodious / there happy / there interesting (wrong)

Again, not good on the adverb front. Next, Preposition Phrases can post-modify nouns. Pronouns and Adverb Phrases can't.

- 4 those men **outside the building**/that box **in the cupboard**.
- 5 those men **there** / that **box there**
- 6 those men **them**/that box **it**. (wrong)
- 7 those men **angrily**/ that box **wonderfully** (wrong)

Here 4 and 5 are ok, suggesting that *there* patterns like a preposition. The adverb and pronoun examples don't fare well though. Note that you could see the phrases in 7 in a sentence, but only if the adverb is describing the verb, not the noun. *That box wonderfully* can't mean something like *that wonderful box*.

Next, the specialized adverbs *right* and *straight*, meaning something like *directly*,  freely modify prepositions  - but not pronouns or adverbs.

- right inside /  right round /straight past/ straight to.
- right there / straight there
- right beautifully / straight unusually (wrong)
- right them / straight they (wrong)

Lastly, pronouns and Preposition Phrases freely function as complements of the verb *BE*. Adverbs don't:

- It's me /  The culprit is you.
- It's outside / The culprit is in the dog basket.
- It's locally / The culprit is wonderfully (wrong)

There are many other tests we can do, but they all show the same thing. *There* always passes tests for prepositions, sometimes passes tests for pronouns and almost never passes tests for adverbs. Given the result of our tests, let's assume that the grammars are right and the dictionaries wrong. *There* is a bona fide locative preposition. In this sentence it's a one-word Preposition Phrase.

So, if we have a Noun Phrase, a verb and a Preposition Phrase, a reasonable hypothesis would be that the Noun Phrase is the Subject, the verb is *BE* and the Preposition Phrase is functioning as the Complement of the verb. (Preposition Phrases don't easily occur as Subject). So now that we have a hypothesis, we're in a position to test if *My biscuit* is the Subject. There are a number of properties that Subjects have that we can test against. No single one of these tests should be taken as being entirely conclusive on its own. These particular tests have been adapted from *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* by Huddleston & Pullum (2002).

**Subjects**

- My biscuit's there!

  > (1) Subjects are *usually* Noun Phrases.

No problems here then. *My biscuit* is indeed a Noun Phrase.

- > (2) Subjects usually occur in the position before the verb.

Likewise, so far so good: *My biscuit* occurs before *is*.

- > (3) Where subjects take case, they are nominative, not accusative.

So basically we can have sentences like *I know them* where *I* is the subject. But *Me know them* won't work.  In ‘*Her, I love* ’, *her* must be the Object and *I* the Subject because *her* is accusative and *I* is nominative.

This is a little tricky with our example. *Biscuit* is a common noun and therefore doesn't take case. The usual thing to do, would be to swap *My biscuit* with a pronoun and see which case the pronoun was. The problem here is that, being genderless, my biscuit is an 'it', not a 'he' or a 'she'. *It* is the same in the nominative and accusative. *I like **it*** and ***it*** likes me. Let's pretend that my biscuit is shaped like Rita Hayworth, and that I have in fact named it after her. I could then refer to it as either 'she' or 'her'. Now we can do a substitution:

- She's there!

So this seems like good news. Our biscuit substitution seems to be nominative.

- > (4) Subjects *usually* determine the person and number of the verb. In other words verbs agree with their Subjects.

Here *my biscuit* is singular. It is also third person. As we would expect, the verb *BE* here is accordingly in the third person singular form: *is*. We could test if this is necessarily so, or incidentally so, by substituting *is* with a first person or a plural form. If the result is still good then this wouldn't validate test 4. If it's bad then it shows that *my biscuit* is actually fully determining the form of the verb:

- My biscuit am there. (wrong!)
- My biscuit are there. (wrong!)

Neither of those is good. This is what we want. We can also check, by making *biscuit* plural and seeing if the verb changes to agree with it:

- My biscuits are there.

This result is good. So everything's on track.

- 

> (5) In yes/no questions, Subjects invert with auxiliary verbs - including the verb *BE*.
>   
>   If we turn ***My biscuit*** is there into a question we get:

- Is **my biscuit** there?

Here we can see that *my biscuit* has dutifully changed places with *is*.

- 

> (6) In an open question  - one with a *wh-* question word - there will be subject auxiliary inversion if the question word is not the Subject. There will be no inversion if the question word *is* the subject.
>   
>   Ok let's replace *my biscuit* with *what*

- What is there?

Ok so the word order doesn't seem to have changed. Both *is* and *there* are in the same position. This seems to show that *my biscuit* is the Subject. Let's check this though. Maybe we would get the same result if we replaced *there* with *where*. This would undermine our result:

- Where is my biscuit.

This time the word order changed dramatically. We can also see that we got Subject auxiliary inversion - *my biscuit* and *is* changed places. *There* can be ruled out for subjecthood here, it seems.

- 

> (7) In question tags, the grammatical number, person, gender and case of the Subject, is reflected in the pronoun that inverts with the auxiliary. 
>   
>   In addition to the above if we substitute the subject with a pronoun, the pronoun in the question tag and the pronoun in the main clause will be the same. Consider:

- Bob likes elephants, **doesn't he**?

Here, *he*, like the Subject is singular, third person, masculine and, importantly, nominative - just like Bob. If we replace *Bob* with pronoun, we get the same pronoun in the sentence and the tag:

- He likes elephants, doesn't he?

Similarly we find:

- My biscuit's there, isn't it?
- My biscuits are there, aren't they?
- It's there isn't it?
- They're there, aren't they.

Again, each pronoun in the question tag agrees in number, person, gender and case with my *biscuit* in the first example and *my biscuits* in the second. They're both third person, neuter, and nominative case. *They*, like *biscuits*, is of course plural. The substituted pronouns are, of course, the very same ones we find in the tags.

- 

> (8) Co-ordination. 
>   Subjects can occur with co-ordinated Verb Phrases
>   
>   For example:

- I [like elephants] and [have always liked elephants]
- My biscuit [is there] and [looks like it's been nibbled].

No problems here then.

- 

> (9) Obligatoriness - Reductions of sentences.
>   
>   Subjects, like verbs, are obligatory in sentences. (We'll disregard imperatives for the moment. These are said to have 'unexpressed' subjects.) If the Subject is removed, the sentence will be badly formed. Secondly, if we reduce the sentence down to its minimal form, the subject should still be represented. So for our sentence:

- Is there! * (wrong)
- My biscuit's there! It is!

The first sentence shows that if you take *my biscuit* away, the sentence is badly formed as we'd expect. The second sentence in the next example shows a minimal version of the sentence, *it is*. Here we see the verb, *is*, and the Subject *it*. *It* here obviously represents *my biscuit*, so again it would seem to confirm that *my biscuit* is probably the subject of sentence 2.

- 

> (10) Uniqueness. There is only ever one Subject in a sentence
>   
>   This isn't really a test so much as an observation, but we can use it to rule out certain items as Subjects. Just to be clear, we can have a co-ordinated Subject, one with the word *and* or perhaps *or*. But this will be one big co-ordinated Subject. So in *Bob and the elephant ate my donuts*, the section *Bob and the elephant* functions as one Subject. What we can show with this with regard to sentence 2, is that because all the evidence shows *my biscuit* to be the Subject, *there* definitely cannot be!

In contrast to Subjects, sentences can have more than one Object, or more than one Complement of a verb:

- I gave the elephant a book voucher.
- The book voucher made her happy.

In the first example there are two Objects of the verb, *the elephant* and *a book voucher*. *Make* in the second sentence has one Complement which is an Object, *her*, and one Predicative Complement, *happy*.

To conclude this section of the post, *My biscuit* is definitely the subject of sentence 2.

[Part the second to follow shortly]

Comment: Did you mean to make this a separate answer altogether? Or did you perhaps hit the max limit when trying to fit it all into one answer? *evil grin*

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Erm, no comment ;) Any huge gaffs?

Comment: Haven’t read through them yet—will let you know if I see anything untowards when I do. :-)

Comment: One huge one: you've misspelt "gaffe" :)

Comment: @chiastic-security Erm, oops! Yep .... if that's the worst one though, I'll be relieved! :) (I'm sure it's not!)

Comment: Very nicely written: thank you. One comment, though. *Subjects, like verbs, are obligatory in sentences. (We'll disregard infinitives for the moment. These are said to have 'unexpressed' subjects.)* Did you mean *imperatives* rather than infinitives? Otherwise it seems we have some more sentences with no subject. (*Stop! Look! Listen!*)

Comment: @chiastic-security Yes, indeed I did. Many thanks. Better dive in for an edit before I mislead lots of folks ...  Aaargg

Comment: There's more!? I thought @tchrist was thorough but you take the biscuit! :P

Comment: Don't want to sound as though you haven't pulled your weight on this question, but is part 2 to be expected soon?

Comment: @chiastic-security Sorry, I did see your comment before I went to bed this morning,  but I forgot about it. Well, it depends what you mean by soon - am in the middle of a big bit of work, so I't trying not to do anything - substantial at least on here till after it has to be in - which is Monday. (am failing here though). So it looks like Tuesday at the mo ...

Comment: @chiastic-security but it's parts 2 and 4, not just part 2 ;)

Comment: No probs :) Just checking you hadn't forgotten.

Comment: Eleven days later...

Comment: @Mari-LouA Hmmm Is this eleven days after the 21st October, when I said I'd start writing the rest of this? Really??? See above, please.

Comment: So what does the footnote [Part the second to follow shortly] mean? Is the post titled *Sentence 3: Existential Subjects: Words, Phrases and Functions* the second part? My comment was also meant to be ambivalent, both your answers are very long.